# How to Split the Date column into periods of one week

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was able to display the Period correctly, but the date assigned to it is not. The first week didn't include the following days: 10, 11, 12, 13 Sep and the second week started earlier, from 11 Sep instead of 14. Of course, this is how it works until the end, with a difference of 3-4 days between the beginning and the end of the period.

[image]

The week should starts on Thursday and ends on Wednesday. This is the formula I used for the Period column:

```
=ArrayFormula(text(A2:A-WEEKDAY(A2:A, 2)+4,"DD-MMM-YY")&" - "&text(A2:A-WEEKDAY(A2:A,2)+10, "DD-MMM-YY"))
```

Also, here is a drive where you can see the data set:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aqndI46TBn99QGJqrTHy75wfj21H-WqeDOcxptyb1Ls/edit#gid=0

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=ArrayFormula(text(A2:A-WEEKDAY(A2:A, 14)+1,"DD-MMM-YY")&" - "&text(A2:A-WEEKDAY(A2:A,14)+7, "DD-MMM-YY"))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great! I can see what you changed, but it's not clear to me why it works.